# Problems with ordering numbers in strings w/ 2 decimals

Tags: python, sorting

So I have a list of version numbers, eg:

`["1.11", "2.0.0", "1.2", "2", "0.1", "1.2.1", "1.1.1", "2.0"]`

and I want to order them from smallest to largest. I found that I can use the `sorted()` function, and that orders it well. Here's the function I came up with:

```
def order(l):

    # Sorts numbers from smallest to largest
    orderedList = sorted(l)

    strList = ""

    for i in range(len(orderedList)):
        strList += orderedList[i]
        
        # Don't put a comma for the last loop
        if i < len(orderedList) - 1: 
            strList += ", "
    
    print(strList)
```

So,

`order(["1.11", "2.0.0", "1.2", "2", "0.1", "1.2.1", "1.1.1", "2.0"])`

currently outputs:

`0.1, 1.1.1, 1.11, 1.2, 1.2.1, 2, 2.0, 2.0.0`.

This may look right, but I need it to order differently.

My desired output is:

`0.1, 1.1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.11, 2, 2.0, 2.0.0`

In other words, I need to tell the program that `1.11` is like `one.eleven`, not a decimal `one.oneone`, and is therefore bigger than `1.2` or `1.2.1`. Similar to Minecraft's versioning system; `1.18` is bigger than `1.8.9`, and I need the function to order the program like that. But the `sorted()` function orders it so that `1.8.9` is bigger than `1.18`

Is there an obvious solution that I've missed?

Is it more complicated than I anticipated?

Do I need to create my own ordering function as an alternative to `sorted()`?

Could I somehow use the *key* parameter in `sorted` to construct my own order? If so, how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're open to other lib. there's a nice one that you can tap in... see the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to sort such that each number in that version is compared to another one in the same position as an `int`eger, so just split by dot, map to `int`, cast to `tuple` for the sorting key, then you can `join` that list and avoid using that `for` loop you have there:

```py
def order(lst):
    lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: tuple(map(int, x.split("."))))
    return ", ".join(lst)


print(order(["1.11", "2.0.0", "1.2", "2", "0.1", "1.2.1", "1.1.1", "2.0"]))
# 0.1, 1.1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.11, 2, 2.0, 2.0.0
```

Comment: This is clever, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is really called *human sort*. And there is a lib for that purpose:

You just have to `pip install natsort` first to get the lib. Why do we need to *reinvent* the wheel instead of focus solving our *real* problem?

```py
import natsort
ans = natsort.natsorted(lst)
ans
['0.1', '1.1.1', '1.2', '1.2.1', '1.11', '2', '2.0', '2.0.0']
```

#### another example

```
heights = '125 inches,11 inches,25 inches,2 inches,100 inches'
sort_heights = natsort.natsorted(heights.split(','))
sort_heights
['2 inches', '11 inches', '25 inches', '100 inches', '125 inches']
```